# Custom equality in Clojure distinct

Tags: clojure

In a Clojure program I've an array composed by maps containing peoples' names and emails.

e.g.

```
[
    { :name "John" :email "john@gmail.com" }  
    { :name "Batman" :email "batman@gmail.com" }  
    { :name "John Doe" :email "john@gmail.com" }  
 ]
```

I'd like to remove the duplicate entries considering, for comparison purposes, pairs having the same e-mail to be equals. In the example above the output would be:

```
[
    { :name "John" :email "john@gmail.com" }  
    { :name "Batman" :email "batman@gmail.com" }  
 ]
```

What's the best way to achieve this in Clojure? Is there a way to let distinct knows what equals function to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would do it: https://crossclj.info/fun/medley.core/distinct-by.html.

The function in the link goes through every value lazily and stores everything it's seen. If the value in the `coll` is already seen, it does not add it.

You could then call this as: `(distinct-by #(% :email) maps)`, where `maps` is your vector of people-maps.

Comment: Since keywords are functions, a more idiomatic invocation would be `(distinct-by :email maps)`

Answer (score 19):

yet another way to do it, kinda more idiomatic, i guess:

```
(let [items [{ :name "John" :email "john@gmail.com" }  
             { :name "Batman" :email "batman@gmail.com" }  
             { :name "John Doe" :email "john@gmail.com" }]]
  (map first (vals (group-by :email items))))
```

output:

```
({:name "John", :email "john@gmail.com"} 
 {:name "Batman", :email "batman@gmail.com"})
```

that is how it works:

`(group-by :email items)` makes a map, whose keys are emails, and values are groups of records with this email

```
{"john@gmail.com" [{:name "John", :email "john@gmail.com"} 
                   {:name "John Doe", :email "john@gmail.com"}], 
 "batman@gmail.com" [{:name "Batman", :email "batman@gmail.com"}]}
```

then you just need to take its vals (groups of records) and select firsts from them.

**And another way** is to create a sorted set by email, so it will treat all the records with equal emails as equal records:

```
(let [items [{ :name "John" :email "john@gmail.com" }  
             { :name "Batman" :email "batman@gmail.com" }  
             { :name "John Doe" :email "john@gmail.com" }]]
  (into (sorted-set-by #(compare (:email %1) (:email %2))) items))
```

output:

```
#{{:name "Batman", :email "batman@gmail.com"} 
  {:name "John", :email "john@gmail.com"}}
```

don't really know which of them is more idiomatic and has a better performance. But i bet on the first one.

Answer (score 4):

A `distinct-by` can easily be implemented as

```
(defn distinct-by [f coll]
  (let [groups (group-by f coll)]
    (map #(first (groups %)) (distinct (map f coll)))))
```

For the example case this can be used like

```
(distinct-by :email
             [{:name "John" :email "john@gmail.com"}  
              {:name "Batman" :email "batman@gmail.com"}  
              {:name "John Doe" :email "john@gmail.com"}])
```